# How can i know swipe viewPager in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

In my application I have `viewPager` and into this `viewPager` I show Video and I set this video into `ViewPagerAdaper`.
I want when swipe right o left, stop video!

I write below codes in `adapter` for show video :

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    View view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_coming_soon, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    final ImageView comingSoonCover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_comingSoonCoverImg);
    final ImageView comingSoonPlayBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_comingSoonPlayBtn);
    final VideoView comingSoonVideoPlayer = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_comingSoon_videoPlayer);
    final RelativeLayout comingSoonImagesLay = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row_comingSoonImagesLay);

    comingSoonPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            comingSoonVideoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(model.get(position).getTrailerDirectLink()));
            comingSoonVideoPlayer.start();
            comingSoonImagesLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

I want when swipe `viewPager`, if `comingSoonVideoPlayer.isPlaying();` , **stop** it and swipe `viewPager`.

How can I it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create stop and star method in your adapter , for example

```
private void start(int position) {
    if(comingSoonVideoPlayer != null {
        comingSoonVideoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(model.get(position).getTrailerDirectLink()));
        comingSoonVideoPlayer.start();
    }
}

private void stop() { 
    if(comingSoonVideoPlayer != null) {
        comingSoonVideoPlayer.stop();
    }
}
```

then in your fragment

```
 mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
           mViewPager.getAdapter().stop();
           mViewPager.getAdapter().start(position);                
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
 });
```

EDIT:

Make `comingSoonVideoPlayer` as a class field :

```
    final VideoView comingSoonVideoPlayer;


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        View view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_coming_soon, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        final ImageView comingSoonCover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_comingSoonCoverImg);
        final ImageView comingSoonPlayBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_comingSoonPlayBtn);
        comingSoonVideoPlayer = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_comingSoon_videoPlayer);
        final RelativeLayout comingSoonImagesLay = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.row_comingSoonImagesLay);

        comingSoonPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
                comingSoonVideoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(model.get(position).getTrailerDirectLink()));
                comingSoonVideoPlayer.start();
                comingSoonImagesLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I want try your codes but I can't it! because I should initialize **VideoView** into `instantiateItem`, such as :         `final VideoView comingSoonVideoPlayer = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_comingSoon_videoPlayer);` . when initialize **VideoView**  global for use other sides, not work me videoView into my app!!! how can I fix it? for use your code I should initialize **VideoView**  globally but I can't initialize this in global!!! why?

Comment: Please see my codes in Post #1 for know my mean. please help me my friend, please

Comment: What's the error when you try to make `comingSoonVideoPlayer` as a class field ?

Comment: For use `comingSoonVideoPlayer` I should initialize as global and I can use this anywhere in adapter? it's ok? but when initialize `comingSoonVideoPlayer` in global (**exit of instantiateItem**), when run application not show video! but when initialize`comingSoonVideoPlayer` into **instantiateItem** app is ok and not any error or bug!

Answer (score 2):

I think this listener can halp you

```
  mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Now it's deprecated. Must using instead `addOnPageChangeListener / removeOnPageChangeListener`

Comment: I should write your code into my fragment but I control video into adapter! how can I it into your code? can you help me and send me code? please

Comment: Somethins like this onPageSelected{ mAdapter.stopOtherPages(position);}

Comment: not found `stopOtherPages` . please send me this code. I want when ssipe viewPager, stop video

Comment: please help me my friend, I really need this. please